# Implementing a Custom Subscription Center in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Has anyone implemented a custom subscription center using landing pages? The example one from the documentation doesn't seem to be working. I would really like to just customized the out of the box one but the amp script is hidden when I view source. Does anyone have and tips/tricks for creating a sub center?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Feel free to update your user name and stay awhile.

Comment: I am trying to do this as well, anyone have a page they build which they can forward me so I can take a look? Dan

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Custom preference centers are generally complex and are often via engagement either with SFMC directly or via SFMC partner.  The ones I've done have taken 30-50 hours depending on the requirements.

As for tips and tricks...

- Understand the SFMC data model and how subscriber statuses are handled for your account type (global, business unit, publication).  Things are handled differently in an [**Enterprise 1.0**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_overview/) account than they are in an [**Enterprise 2.0**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/) account.
- Use [**Server-Side JavaScript**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/) to leverage arrays and functions.  The coding can be done entirely in AMPScript, but it's easier to create object-oriented code in SSJS.
- Utilize the [**SOAP examples**](http://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Documentation/APIStarterKits/SOAPv3.zip) when structuring your API calls
- Be sure to correctly [**log unsub events**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm) when handling unsubscribes
- I normally build preference centers in 4 pages:

  1. **Subscription Center Page** - subscribers opt-in and out of lists or publications marked as Public.
  2. **Profile Center Page** - subscribers update their information (emailaddress, name, zipcode, etc).
  3. **One-Click Unsubscribe Page** - subscribers are immediately unsubscribed from the publication used as the send audience in your SFMC account (or globally if it's not specified) and
  4. **Results Page** - a thank your or error page depending on the action taken on pages 1-3.

**2021-10-28 Update**:

[Here's the boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) that I use.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. For a start to understanding everything, why can't I simply copy this: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api/.   Into a landing page and have it work. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: The code sample is dependent on you visiting from an encoded URL.  You'll need to build an email that links to your new page and send it to a test list (that contains your email address) using a Guided Send.  Build the links in your email using the `MicrositeURL()` AMPScript function.

Comment: Do you have any sample html from sub enters you have created?

Comment: Not that I can share, no.  I'd be glad to answer specific questions you have as you're writing your code.

Comment: Thanks, what URLs go in the form action parameters? I've seen it different in multiple examples.

Comment: Depends on how you'd like to process it.  I've done it with a separate page to process the POST or with the page posting it to itself and detecting POST vs GET.  Here's an skeleton of a pref center page that posts to itself: http://pastebin.com/6sai85pY

Comment: This is great Adam thanks. I think my goal right now is going to be to get the sample page(Profile Center Download): https://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Attachments/AdminCustomProfileCenterPages.zip working, and style it differently. Unfortunately it does not work because I don't have an AdminPageInfo data extension (don't have that feature in ET). Would that be the only reason this page doesn't work? If i comment that line out, the page loads but the form doesn't send correctly.

Comment: The page can be coded to work with Lists instead of Data Extensions.  I suggest reading up on the SSJS functions: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/

Comment: Thanks for the info Adam. Unfortunalty I don't even know where to begin modifying the sample page to run with lists instead. I'm going to read up and hopefully figure something out.