# Subscription center - exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to re-style the subscription center that exact target puts in every email. Are there ways to do this? I don't want to have to recode an entire sub center if the logic is the same as the one provided.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ET's Brandbuilder, which does this very kind of thing.  You will need to have it enabled in your account, so talk to your ET rep to get that done. Have a look at [this page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/imh_brandbuilder/) for the "how-to".

Comment: Thanks but unfortunalty that's just for colors and logos. I was looking to style the page like our companies website

Comment: There is some flexibility with ET's brand tags, but you'll need to contact ET Support.  Otherwise you're stuck doing what you asked in your previous post (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47247/implementing-custom-subscription-center-exact-target/47267)

Comment: Thanks again Adam. I'm just really frustrated about getting their sample to work here: https://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Attachments/AdminCustomProfileCenterPages.zip I would assume it should work just copying it over, but I must be doing something wrong